# DLRS - Rolling Up Most Recent Call Duration from Task to Contact

Tags: dlrs

I want to use DLRS to transfer the CallDurationInSeconds from the most recently completed Task up to the Contact. I've configured my rollup like so, but I'm receiving an error: "Master and detail fields must be the same field type (or text/Id based) for First or Last operations"

[image]

Both CallDurationInSeconds and Last_Call_Duration__c are of the type Number(8,0), so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain (I don't have a DLRS org handy to test on), but I think the source of this issue is that `CallDurationInSeconds` is one of the handful of standard fields that have the underlying type `int` (see the [SOAP Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm)).

You can't create custom fields of that type; your custom number fields are of type `double`, regardless of their precision/scale and whether they're Numbers, Currency, or Percent fields.

One possible workaround might be to create a formula field on Activity of type Number that references the `CallDurationInSeconds` field. I suspect that will yield a roll-up-able value.

Comment: I previously had the aggregate field as a Number(18,0), and thought I was real clever switching it to match the digits, but this makes sense.